# How to sort BehaviorSubject data?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have replaced `this.userrights` to `userrights$` observable:

```
public userrights$: Observable<UserRight[]>;
```

Before was a filter method is called from template by click event:

```
filterState(state: UserRightState) {
    this.userrights = this.clonned.filter((st: UserRight) => (this.filterBy == state ? true : st.value === getRightStateValue(state)));
    this.filterBy = this.filterBy == state ? null : state;
}
```

How to rewrite it on RXJS?

I have createed a new subject that contains filter state `public state$ = new Subject<UserRightState >()`.

How to filter BehaviorSubject data and return back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have both filterBy and the list you want to filter in two Observables you can use `combineLatest()`:

```
filterBy$ = new BehaviorSubject<UserRightState | null>(null);
allUserRights$ = new BehaviorSubject<UserRight[]>([]);

userrights$ = combineLatest([
  filterBy$.pipe(
    pairwise(),
    map(([prevState, state]) => prevState === state ? null : state),
  ), // This will take care of toggling filterBy.
  allUserRights$,
]).pipe(
  map(([filterBy, userRights]) => userRights.filter(/* do whatever with `filterBy` */))
)

filterState(state: UserRightState) {
  filterBy$.next(state);
}
```

If you know that `this.clonned` will never change you can remove `combineLatest` of course.

Comment: Thank you a lot! There is a problem, after filter I can not reset state to initial state to sort again

Comment: How do you reset the filter?

Comment: toggling filterBy

Comment: that means what values you're using? For example you use `null`, `col1`, `null`, `col1`? Or you're emitting `col1`, `col1`, `col1`?

Comment: For example there is a full list: [1,2,3,4]. I pressed 4, it was sorted by 4 and retuns [4]. When I press again I should get all list [1,2,3,4]

Answer (score 1):

You can `map` the observable to another observable:

```
const filteredRights$ = userrights$.pipe(
 map(rights => rights.filter(rights => // whatever condition))
);
```